# Is there a way to get better code suggestions for Flutter/Dart widget properties within VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, intellicode

Is there an extension or way to get better code suggestions for Flutter/Dart widget properties when it's expecting a certain type of value?  The image below shows a Column widget property of mainAxisAlignment and it's "code suggestions" and Flutter documentation.  It expects an enum value of type MainAxisAlignment, but the code suggestions are basically worthless.  I have to type quite a few characters to get to the enum type to show up before I can get autocomplete to kick in for one of the values.  Is there an intellicode-type extension or way to get better suggestions to show up?  Even if they bubbled up to the top after typing them a few times, it would be helpful.  Android Studio seems to do this, but I much prefer VS Code and would rather stay in my editor of choice if possible.  Thanks.

[Code suggestions when only specific enum allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhAFo.png)

Comment: Hi. In your example, what would it show when you typed "Ma"?